# Use a React Component in Redux form "Field" Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have to implement a react-phone-number package in a redux form. I am new to reactjs and redux. I have to tranform my React code to one of the field in redux form. Here is the react code.

```
import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import IntlTelInput from 'react-intl-tel-input';
    import '../node_modules/react-intl-tel-input/dist/main.css';
    import '../node_modules/react-intl-tel-input/dist/libphonenumber.js';


    const loadJSONP = (url, callback) => {
      const ref = window.document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      const script = window.document.createElement('script');
      script.src = `${url + (url.indexOf('?') + 1 ? '&' : '?')}callback=${callback}`;
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(script, ref);
      script.onload = () => {
        script.remove();
      };
    };

    const lookup = (callback) => {
      loadJSONP('http://ipinfo.io', 'sendBack');
      window.sendBack = (resp) => {
        const countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : '';
        callback(countryCode);
      }
    };

    const handler = (status, value, countryData, number, id) => {
      console.log(status, value, countryData, number, id);
    };

    ReactDOM.render(
      <IntlTelInput 
        onPhoneNumberChange={ handler }

        preferredCountries={['us','ca']}
        css={ ['intl-tel-input', 'form-control'] }
      />, 
      document.getElementById('root'),
    );
```

Now I want to somehow use it in "Field" component of Redux-Form which is something like below.

```
const FieldCountryCode = ({
  name,
  label,
  placeholder,
  value,
  showsRequired,
}: PropsT) => (
  <Field
    name={name}
    component={IntlTelInput}
    props={{
      label,
      placeholder,
      type: 'tel',
      value,
      showsRequired,
    }}
  />
);

export default FieldCountryCode;
```

The Problem I am facing is that when I try to do something with the component attribute of Field it loses its CSS contents. Here is the link to describe how actually it should work. [link](http://patw0929.github.io/react-intl-tel-input/)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line

```
import '../node_modules/react-intl-tel-input/dist/main.css';
```

from the above component and add it to the top of your main `App.js` file in the root.

If that doesn't work than try copying the file itself and include it in your `index.html` directly using the HTML `<link />` tag. (Just make sure you create the copy of that file and add it in your `public` folder. You won't be able to refer it from the node_modules directory.)

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of the docs [here](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/field.md/#-code-props-object-code-optional-) is correct, the `props` property is used to pass down props to the component actually being rendered, with the `component` prop. In other words, do `<Field component={IntlTelInput} props={{ test: 123 }} />` and the `Field` component does something along the lines of `<IntlTelInput test={123} />`.

The solution is to put the appropriate props needed in the `Field`'s `props` prop. Given your first example, it should be something like this:

```
<Field
  name={name}
  component={IntlTelInput}
  props={{
    preferredCountries: ["us", "ca"],
    css: ["intl-tel-input", "form-control"],
    onPhoneNumberChange: onChange,
  }}
/>
```

The lack of styling was probably due to the missing `css` prop. Also remember to define that `onChange` prop to this component.

Comment: Could you give more detail than "isn't working"? Does the app still run, just without styles? Are you getting any error message?

Comment: The app works but the flags which should be seen in the left corner of the field doesnt work + I get all the list already displayed in text on the form @kingdaro

Comment: No error message but I think its just not loading the css file @kingdaro

Comment: Can you tell me where should I import the CSS file? Like I have imported in one of the Components but I have tried putting it as said by @Aditya